# Select ancestor based on the attribute value of the selected node

Tags: xml, xpath, .net-6.0, xpath-1.0

input.xml file -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sg:EmployeeDetails xmlns:sg="http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd">
    <sg:FirstName>Sagar</sg:FirstName>
    <sg:MiddleName>H</sg:MiddleName>
    <sg:LastName>Shinde</sg:LastName>
    <sg:EmailId>sagarharidasshinde@gmail.com</sg:EmailId>
    <sg:Mobile>9021063389</sg:Mobile>
    <sg:Years>
        <sg:Year>1954</sg:Year>
        <sg:Year>1980</sg:Year>
        <sg:Year>1954</sg:Year>
    </sg:Years>
    <sg:Address>135/214, Hindustan Chowk, Mulund Colony, Mulund (W) - 400082</sg:Address>
    <sg:Cars>
        <sg:Car id="car1" year="1980"  condition="count(./ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year[text() = //sg:Car[@id='car1']/@year]) &gt;=0" message="Driver must be 100 yrs old.">BMW</sg:Car>
        <sg:Car id="car2" year="1954" condition="count(./ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year[text() = //sg:Car[@id='car1']/@year]) &gt;=0" message="Driver must be 100 yrs old.">BMW</sg:Car>
    </sg:Cars>
</sg:EmployeeDetails>
```

I am going to parse this xml file using .net 6. I will select all nodes with attribute 'condition' with xpath as -

```xml
//Car[@condition]
```

I will iterate thru' each node found with the captioned expression, and then evaluate if the expression in the value of the condition attribute is true. (I can not use xs:assert as .net6 does not support xsd1.1)

I would like to set the value of the condition attribute such that I can find if there is at least one ancestor node of 'EmployeeDetails' with more than one 'Year' child-node, having value that matches value of the 'year' attribute of the car node whose 'condition' attribute's value is being evaluated.

```cs
                string xmlFilePath = "input.xml";
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.Schemas.Add("http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd", "input.xsd"); 
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings))
                {
                    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                    document.Load(reader);
                    
                    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("sg", "http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd");

                    document.Validate(eventHandler);
                    // Read the XML content and validate against the schema

                    var nav = document.CreateNavigator();
                    var list = nav.Select("//sg:Car[@condition]", nsmgr);
                    while(list.MoveNext())
                    {
                        var item = list.Current;
                        var condition = item.GetAttribute("condition", "");
                        var result = item.Evaluate(condition, nsmgr);
                        if (!(bool)result)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Validation error:Validation error");
                        }
                    }

                }
```

This code works fine.

I would to remove reference of  '//sg:Car[@id='car1']' from

```xml
count(./ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year[text() = //sg:Car[@id='car1']/@year]) &gt;=0
```

and make it something like

```xml
count(./ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year[text() = @year]) &gt;=0
```

This exact expression fails as '@year' is searched in the sg:Year node instead of sg:Car node.

Does any one has any idea how to do that?

For completeness the input.xsd file is as below -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd"
        xmlns:sg="http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="EmployeeDetails">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="MiddleName">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="EmailId" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Mobile" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="Years">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Year" type="sg:Year" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Address">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:minLength value="5"/>
                            <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Cars" type="sg:Cars"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Cars">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Car" type="sg:Car" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Car">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="sg:CarModel">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="year" type="sg:Year" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="condition" type="xs:string" use="optional"  />
                <xs:attribute name="message" type="xs:string" use="optional" fixed="Driver must be 100 yrs old."/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="CarModel">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Audi"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Golf"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="BMW"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="Year">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1900" />
            <xs:maxInclusive value="2200" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: There are (commercial) libraries for XSD 1.1 support in .NET 6, like SaxonCS. It is also possible, using IKVM, to run Apache Xerces Java from Maven as cross-compiled .NET code so that you even have an open-source solution to use XSD 1.1 with assertions and .NET 6.

Comment: Also, you can use more expressive and powerful XPath versions like the current version XPath 3.1 in .NET 6, again using commercial libraries like SaxonCS or using IKVM cross compiled Saxon HE 10 or 11 or 12 Java.

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen
I think all of them are paid ones. I can use only free ones.

Comment: No, using IKVM and Saxon HE for XPath 3.1 is possible without paying a license. As is using IKVM and Apache Xerces for XSD 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of XPath 1.0, I think it should work to just check

```
@year = ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year
```

in the context of the `sg:Car` element. That condition is only true if there is a year match.

As for doing it with open-source software and XPath 3.1, you can use Saxon HE 10 cross-compiled with IKVM to .NET (Core) as follows:

```
using Saxon.Api;
using System.Xml;

string xmlFilePath = "input2.xml";
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas.Add("http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd", "input.xsd");
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.Severity} {e.Message}");
};

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings))
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(reader);

    Processor processor = new Processor(false);

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

    XdmNode wrappedDoc = docBuilder.Wrap(document);

    XPathCompiler xpathCompiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();

    xpathCompiler.DeclareNamespace("", "http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd");
    xpathCompiler.DeclareNamespace("sg", "http://sg.iaea.org/ssac-qs/qsSchema.xsd");

    foreach (XdmNode car in xpathCompiler.Evaluate("//Car[@condition]", wrappedDoc))
    {
        var conditionEvaluationResult = xpathCompiler.EvaluateSingle(car.GetAttributeValue("condition"), car) as XdmAtomicValue;
        if (!conditionEvaluationResult.GetBooleanValue())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Validation failed for Car {car.GetAttributeValue("id")} with year {car.GetAttributeValue("year")}.");
        }
    }

}
```

Your .NET project would have e.g.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SaxonHE10Net31Api" Version="10.9.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

your conditions would be (I think you want `>` not `>=`) e.g.

```
<sg:Car id="car3" year="1984" condition="let $car := . return count(ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year[. = $car/@year]) &gt;0" message="Driver must be 100 yrs old.">BMW</sg:Car>
```

Example .NET 6 console project is at https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonHE10Net6XPath31Example1.

Disclaimer: Saxon 10 HE is an open-source product from Saxonica that  exists on NuGet from Saxonica itself, but only for .NET framework; the project SaxonHE10Net31Api used and referenced above is my recompilation/rebuild of that open source project for .NET (Core) aka .NET 3.1 and later.

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen
How would the condition attribute in sg:Car node look like with your expression?

Comment: As shown: `@year = ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year`

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen your code.
I have decided to go ahead with just .net 6 and not to use Saxon. It looks but heavy to me with dependency on tar file(s) and Maven Repo.

I guess the condition you suggested i.e. 

<sg:Car id="car3" year="1984" condition="let $car := . return count(ancestor::sg:EmployeeDetails/sg:Years/sg:Year[. = $car/@year]) &gt;0" message="Driver must be 100 yrs old.">BMW</sg:Car>

does no work with .net6. I tried it and get error -  "has an invalid token".

Comment: @RavirajBhalerao, well, if I point out that you need Saxon to use XPath 3.1 it doesn't make sense that you point out to me that the part of the answer with XPath 3.1 doesn't work for you if you don't use Saxon. Either use the built-in XPath 3.1 support or use third party libraries for up to date XPath support, Microsoft certainly hasn't made any effort in supporting anything but XPath 1.0, thus if .NET 6 for you means just the Microsoft provided classes and no third party libraries then fine, but my answer made it clear that the XPath 3.1 example needs a third party library.